# How to observer nested objects using MVC design pattern

Tags: java, model-view-controller, design-patterns

I am trying to use the MVC design pattern to observe objects within the model class. for example the model class represents a building which has x number of floors and each floor has a door, how would you observer the door which is inside the floor object. How would the view objects reach the door object to register themselves as observers?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe what you want is the Observer Pattern:

[image]

The pattern has an observer object that listens for events and notify all listeners when that event occurs. You can made your building a observer and check for modifications in the doors, when something changes you can notify all the listeners. Now your building is a observer the views can register as a listener.
Here is a simple code example:

Here is the building class that acts as a observer:

```
class Building {

    List<Observers> listeners = new ArrayList<>();

    public void checkDoors(){
        //check for variations...
        if(variation) notifyListeners(); //iterate over all observers and notify them
    }


    public void addListener(Listener listener){
        listeners.add(listener);
    }
}
```

And here is the view that listens for notifications on doors:

```
class View implements Listener {

    public View(Building building){

        building.addListener(this);
    }

    void handleDoor(Door door){
        //do some stuff...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, so the building (model) would be using the observer pattern on each of the doors for each floor? Is this still valid MVC pattern?

Comment: You can mix design patterns to increase functionality. Your controller will be the observer and watch for events on doors to notify the listeners. Is still a valid MVC pattern since you use views for rendering, controllers to handle business logic and models to handle data management and persistence.